# AutoPostBack revert changes that I made with the event onChange. ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Theses are the controls that im using in asp.net. Everything is inside an UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtDoc" runat="server" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="TipoDoc" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Codebehind:

```
TipoDoc.Attributes.Add("onChange", "cambiarLength(this, '" + TxtDoc.ClientID + "');");
```

When I select an item from the dropdownlist "TipoDoc" the function cambiarLength changes the maxlength of the textbox "TxtDoc".
When I select an item from the second dropdownlist "Ddl2" since the autopostback is true, the maxlength from the previous textbox is reverted to the initial value. How can I avoid such a problem like that?

Comment: You need to store the state of your textbox on the server somehow. An option would be to set AutoPostBack=True on `TipoDoc` and perform the MaxLength calculation on the server.

Comment: @ferc im trying to avoid doing the validation on the server for that dropdownlist, and validate from client side. Is it really necessary to store the state of that textbox on the server if a postback is fired? Is it possible to avoid that using multiple updatepanels?

Comment: Okay, I found that I could use hiddenfields to retain the values from client-side and retrieve them again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    { 
        TipoDoc.Attributes.Add("onChange", "cambiarLength(this, '" + TxtDoc.ClientID + "');");
    }   
}
```